# Detect Mailto vs Http/Https in array items and open Http urls in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

I have the following View model in ko.js: (with the Helplink array)

```
function initializeViewModel(vm) {
  vm.helpLinks.push(new HelpLink('http://yyy.com', "Error Message/My access isn't working for..."));
  vm.helpLinks.push(new HelpLink("mailto:xxx@xx.com", "Contact Research ", "ID Request/I need an ID for..."));
  vm.helpLinks.push(new HelpLink("https://yyyyy.ggg.com", "Go to Assist Me form", "Assist Me Request/Please send me research on..."));
  vm.helpLinks.push(new HelpLink("mailto:xxx@xx.com", "Contact Research Center", "Training request"));
}
```

//Html Markup

```
 <a href="#" data-bind="visible: chosenHelpLink,
                    text: chosenHelpLink().linkText,
                    attr: { href: chosenHelpLink().url }" style="display: none;" class="primary"></a>
```

I want to force the array items that have a Http/https url to open in a new tab. The mailto links should be left as is.

I was playing around with the following snippet:

```
 if (window.location.protocol(HelpLink) == "http:") {
        window.open ... 
    }
```

Unfortunately, i cannot get the function to work at all. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, the change you provided would not work in my case as the HTML markup would need to stay the same (the options are displayed as a drop down menu thus the div cannot be added). I have attached also an image on the render: http://imgur.com/a/OGrH6

Answer (score 0):

What about using a computed and simply separate bindings?

Here's a short demo to hopefully explain it.

```js
function HelpLink(url, text) {
  var self = this;
  self.url = ko.observable(url);
  self.text = ko.observable(text);
  self.https = ko.computed(function(){
   if(url.match(/^https/)) return true;
    else return false;
  })
}

function ViewModel() {
  self.helpLinks = ko.observableArray();
  self.helpLinks.push(new HelpLink('http://yyy.com', "Error Message/My access isn't working for..."));
  self.helpLinks.push(new HelpLink("mailto:xxx@xx.com", "Contact Research ", "ID Request/I need an ID for..."));
  self.helpLinks.push(new HelpLink("https://yyyyy.ggg.com", "Go to Assist Me form", "Assist Me Request/Please send me research on..."));
  self.helpLinks.push(new HelpLink("mailto:xxx@xx.com", "Contact Research Center", "Training request"));


}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: helpLinks">

<a data-bind="visible: true,
                    text: text,
                    attr: { href: url, target: https() ? '_blank' : '' }" style="display: none;" class="primary"></a><br>
  
</div>
```

Edit:
I modified my original answer to avoid editing html.

The binding will have to be updated for every solution I can imagine. Attr binding lets you set any attribute you need. Using a computed to determine https or not you can then use the ternary operator (`? :`) to evaluate if target should be changed.

Comment: The html markup cannot be modified thus a computed function would not help in this case. I was thinking more like targeting the first or second element in the array (i can arrange them accordingly) and force that specific element to open in a new tab rather then filtering by http

Comment: @RazvanIrimie I've updated my answer. You can do it without editing html, but the binding does need to be updated.